# merge rows in android tableviewlayout instead of cells?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I know we can merge cells in android using span propriety.

But what if i want to merge two rows for any one cell? And i want to show any single view in that both row of that cell.

Please advise me. Thanks in advance. :)